# Multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a Python code running that shows the first year that certain conditions are met. This has to be done in two steps. I am unable to see what I am doing wrong.

The program is loading a CSV file in. I have created two lists

```
for a in reader:            
        temperature = [int(a['TX'])]
        day = [int(a['DATE'])]
```

The next step is an iteration over range of a length of temperature:

```
for x in range(len(temperature)):
```

The next step is a while-loop:

```
while temperature[x]>= 250 and temperature[x+1] >= 250
```

The following I am doing is:

```
            temp_temperature = [temperature[x]]
            temp_day = [x]
```

The logic behind would be that all temperatures that meet the while loop are saved in the list along with the index of the temperature.

The temperature has to meet the condition that it is five consecutive days above 25 degrees. If it has met this condition, it it has to verify that the temperature is above 30 degrees for three consecutive days. If this is the case, it has to print the first occurrence of both conditions.

In-case a condition is not met:

```
            i += 0
            temp_day.clear()
            temp_temperature.clear()
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Comment: In the first loop you presented, the construct `var = [something]` makes your variables store a list with a single entry. Consider initializing them before as `var = []` and then using the `append` method as `var.append(something)`

Comment: `temperature[x-1]` will be `temperature[-1]` on the first iteration, which is the last element of the list.

Comment: Consider using slicing and the `all()` function to test if something is true for all days in a range.

Comment: Can you post your code as a whole so that we can run and test it for ourselves? This would include a sample of your csv file :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the issue with your help! The issue was that I had to use a initialize the list first and append it afterwards. So this resulted in:

```
tempature = []
day = []

for a in reader:            
        temperature.append(int(a['TX']))
        day.append(int(a['DATE']))
```